# Maximize button in a Google Chrome Packaged App

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How can you implement a window maximize button in a Google Chrome packaged app?

More precisely: how do you maximize the window in Javascript programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

`maximize()` on [`AppWindow`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window.html#type-AppWindow)

([You need to design your own button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483563/where-are-the-min-max-buttons-on-new-chrome-packaged-apps?rq=1))

Comment: you have a typo, it should be maximize()